# Python + sqlalchemy: how to process timedelta on database side?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, func, timedelta

Coding with Python, I want to insert time processed on the database side like this:

```
time = func.now()-datetime.timedelta(days=100)
```

or

```
time = func.current_timestamp()-datetime.timedelta(days=100)
```

but somehow it couldn't get through, seeing warning:

```
sqlalchemy\engine\default.py:330: Warning: Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '1970-01-04 00:00:00'
```

Any way to get it straight? thanks.

================================

I want to update a TIMESTAMP column 'date_buy' in table 'Purchase', an d instead of using datetime.datetime.now() to get the update time in python, I want to get this done in the database, meaning I would prefer func.now():

```
time = func.current_timestamp()-datetime.timedelta(days=100)
# time = datetime.datetime.now()-datetime.timedelta(days=100)
session.execute(update(Purchase).values(date_buy=time).where(Purchase.c.id == 11))
```

=================================

solved. thanks to Bryan and his post:
http://groups.google.com/group/sqlalchemy/browse_thread/thread/a67d4f179e01b98a/ee688a0b8a999f52?hl=en&lnk=gst&q=date_add#ee688a0b8a999f52

Comment: If you found the solution then accept the answer to close the question. Please do this to complete the workflow of the system.

Answer (score 2):

The Warning is

`Warning: Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '1970-01-04 00:00:00'`

Means its truncating your data. Please check your field type in which you are going to store the time object. **It says that you are trying to store DOUBLE value with datetime value.**

If this will not solve the problem then just give some code example so we will get idea what you are going to do.

Comment: pls take a look at the edited post. i am not sure if this is a right way to leave the operation on that field to MySQL, not python. thanks!

Comment: What is the type of date_buy? Please provide the class of Purchase.

Comment: CURRENTTIMESTAMP is double value and you are trying to minus datetime from CURRENTTIMESTAMP. Just use same type of operand to perform the operation. You can use `converttimestamp(func.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=100))`